# Send e-mail via Javascript inside AngularJS with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, parse-platform

There is one way to send e-mails via Javascript inside AngularJS? I am use parse.com too but I don't now how to do this function. Isn't  required to do with parse.com.

I have read that it can to be possible if I use SendGrid or Mandrill but I need pay to use it?

Comment: You'd need some mail service to connect to (either an SMTP server or a service which itself uses an SMTP server).  Do you have one?

Comment: @David but SendGrid or Mandrill don't do this service?

Comment: i used mailgun for one of my apps..it was very easy

Comment: @varunaaruru how I can use it inside AngularJS?

Comment: @Deise: I don't personally know what services they offer.  If you want to find out, you might try going to their websites and looking at their information.

Comment: I did for my ionic mobile app, you need to register your app in mailgun and it will give you an api key.you need to pass that in your controller .

Comment: @varunaaruru but my app is web in Javascript, can you show me your code? If it is in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site have the resolution: https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-static-websites-using-parse/

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a client side JavaScript framework.

That said, you may want to do two things :

- provide a `mailto:` link, which will call the client's email application
- or provide a form which permit to send the email content to a web service on back end

If you was thinking about the second option (I can't tell, your question isn't what I called "complet"), try to search an API online.

What you're trying to do (use a client side application to send email via a app account) is a really wrong approach,

Comment: My problem is that it need to do without service back end. I would like some in JS with Mandrill or SendGrid by Cloud Code Parse.